# C# Wake Drives in 32 bit Subsytem

Tags: c#, winapi, com-interop

I have a commercial Application that runs under 64 bit Windows as a 32 bit application.  The app's 8+ GB of data libraries (not DLLs) are installed on a network share that must be mapped to a local drive for the app to work properly.  It doesn't use UNCs.  When I start the app, it doesn't see the mapped drive and shows it as being offline with a red slash through the icon.  I can manually wake the mapped drive up by opening a file dialog in the software, but that requires 6 clicks.

In the OS, the mapped drive is active and immediately returns file listings, so I'm guessing that there are completely separate 32 bit and 64 bit representations of connected/disconnected drives in Windows 7.  Another guess is that the app is calling the wrong API to determine if the drives are available.

This lead me to want to quickly program an app to ping the mapped drive in the 32 bit subsystem.  I figured I'd use some c#/interop and it would be a 15 minute job.  Unfortunately, that didn't turn out to be the case.  My 32 bit C# app uses GetDevicePowerState and reports that the drive is already active.

If you've seen this behavior before, what API would one use to cause the drives to become active?

Comment: Might help us to know how this application is linking to "it's libraries".  Are these just normal assemblies sitting on a network share?  Because it sounds like there may be a lot going on there.  More info would help.

Comment: What??? We're supposed to "guess" which APIs are being called from an application we know nothing about and you've shared almost nothing about? Unsure how we're supposed to answer that. Your entire post and the 3 questions asked are completely off-topic or unanswerable.

Comment: For that matter, what does it mean to "wake up" a mapped drive? How are we supposed to figure out why your app doesn't work properly without even seeing any code???

Comment: I modified the question to be more obviously on-topic.

Comment: You're going to spend time writing code to bodge this rather than the obvious fix of "stop using network drives and use UNC paths instead"?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the question again to indicate that this is a commerical application.  I don't have the source code for it.

Comment: @tnw - Wake the drive: meaning to trigger Windows to reconnect a mapped drive.  Windows will automatically disconnect mapped network resources after a time period of disuse.  The concept is similar to having the monitor go from an unpowered state to a powered state when a key is pressed on the keyboard.  The "guess at the API" part is more relevant to devs that have experience with uncertified Windows apps that often didn't use the best practices when calling APIs.

Comment: I'd suggest using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to work out what filesystem calls the application *is* making when it starts up. That would be better than trying to guess what it's doing.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I had never used procmon to look at stack traces, only for resource access issues.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I have a bunch of log data to review now...